# Радувати чи тішити?

Tags: вживання-слів, калька

[На деяких сайтах](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE/) знайшла інформацію про те, що "радувати око" — скалькований вислів. І його потрібно замінити висловом "тішити око".

Чи варто тоді вживати слово "радувати" як самостійне? Чи краще вживати "тішити"?

Особисто мені подобається другий варіант. І я взагалі думала, що в українській мові немає "радувати". Але у СУМ-11 воно є:

> [РАДУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/raduvaty), ую, уєш, недок., перех. Викликати почуття радості. <…>
>
> [ТІШИТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/tishyty), шу, шиш, недок., перех. 1. Робити комусь приємність, бути комусь втіхою; радувати кого-небудь. <…>

Comment: Ну, однокорінні слова на _-рад-_ в українській мові очевидно є (_радий_, _радісний_, _радість_, _радіти_, _радощі_). Та й письменники-класики його вживали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Справді, багато джерел ([Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE/), [сайт Мовник](https://movnyk.com.ua/question/vzivannya-raduvati-oko/), [словник Волощака](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=25&t=4922), [словник-антисуржик](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=19&t=1425)) вказують на те, що потрібно казати "тішити око" (або ж веселити/розвеселити - [джерело](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5&table=uk_fraz)).

Однак, зверну увагу на Онлайн Корректор, там не пише "помилка", а "не рекомендовано", тобто якщо ми скажемо "радувати око", то це не буде абсолютною помилкою. Хоч це і є калька з російської, та цей вислів також вживається як в творах класичної української літератури (***Тече Псьол… Тече, на сонці вилискує, землю поїть, ліси годує і око радує.. (Остап Вишня)*** ), так і зустрічається не лише в СУМі, але й в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8). Можливо редактори цих словників допустилися цієї помилки саме через те, що скалькований варіант досить часто зустрічається у літературних творах.

Однак, варто все ж таки казати **"тішити/веселити око/серце"**.

На рахунок самого слова "радувати", дивно, але в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf) його немає. Однак, бачимо його в СУМі і словнику синонімів, а також в російсько-українському словнику на [Академіку](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC/ru/uk/). Лише ось тут (не вважаю надійним джерелом) я знайшов, що "[радувати](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1019076797.html)" - це русизм. Сказати чи це так досить складно, бо й справді є стара українська колядка "Ой радуйся Земле".

То як бути? Як я вже писав, краще уникати вислову "радувати око", однак гадаю вживання самого слова "радувати" не буде помилкою, бо якихось фактів, які б доводили те, що це русизм я не знайшов.

Comment: Щодо «радувати око», то я не розумію, звідки взагалі взялася версія, що це помилка, якщо воно вживається в письменників і є подібні ідіоми «веселити око», «тішити око».

Comment: Трішки доповнив відповідь.
Справді дивно, що слова "радувати" немає в ЕСУМі.

Comment: «Ой радуйся, земле» — теж спало на думку :).

Answer (score 1):

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) знаходимо ці слова як синоніми:

> РА́ДУВАТИ (викликати почуття радості); ТІ́ШИТИ,

Однак, у [Словнику-антисуржика](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53408/300343.html) також знаходимо:

> РАДУВАТИ ОКО - тішити око.

Цікаво, що у словниковій статті [радувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/raduvaty) знаходимо фразеологізм:

> РАДУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., перех. Викликати почуття радості.
>
> ♦ Радувати око (очі) див. око 1.

і в словниковій статті [тішити](http://sum.in.ua/s/tishyty) також знаходимо такий фразеологізм:

> **ТІШИТИ**, шу, шиш, недок., перех.
>
> ♦ Тішити око (вухо, зір, слух і т. ін.) — викликати приємне відчуття своїм виглядом, звучанням і т. ін.

Незрозуміло чим можна пояснити те, що словник-антисуржик подає одну інформацію, а [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/) іншу.

Comment: Можливо, я помиляюся, але мені здається, yulia17 питала перш за все про саме слово «радувати», а не про словосполучення «радувати око».

Comment: так, як самостійне)